# Connection Error : Max retries exceeded with url:/API/Admin/login.php

Tags: django, api

I am running my django application in local host and i tried with my IP address as well. I am getting the connection error.  My views.py file is below

```
def user_login(request):
datas= {'log':False}
if request.method == "POST":
    usern=request.POST.get('username')
    passw=request.POST.get('password')
    response = requests.post(url='https://www.onebookingsystem.com/API/Admin/login.php',data={"Username":usern,"password":passw},timeout=5)
    json_data = response.json()
```

The error which i am getting is given below.

```
 File "C:\Users\Android V\Anaconda3\envs\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.onebookingsystem.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /productionApi/API/Admin/login.php (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000054620B8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refusedit',))
```

[09/Oct/2019 18:28:21] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 156251

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use headers like this:

```
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
request = requests.post("https://www.onebookingsystem.com/API/Admin/login.php",headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried using headers, but the same error is occuring. i even switched off firewall but no changes